reinterpret bytes of buffer according to system(native) endianess
I am receiving data from an another host via network socket in big endian format. How to interpret the bytes received in the native endian format(like get a view or reintrepret those bytes) without copying into a temporary variable.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct A {
    uint16_t msg_id;
    // contains many other fields where total size is greater than 4096

    void print() const {
        // print all the fields of struct A
    }
};

struct B {
    uint16_t msg_id;
    // contains many other fields where total size is greater than 4096

    void print() const {
        // print all the fields of struct B
    }
};

struct C {
    uint16_t msg_id;
    // contains many other fields where total size is greater than 4096

    void print() const {
        // print all the fields of struct C
    }
};

int main() {
    char buff[8192];
    while (true) {
        // data is received in network byte order (big endian) but my system is little endian
        const auto recvd_len = recvfrom(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        const uint16_t msg_id = (buff[0] << 8) | (buff[1] & 0xFF);

        switch (msg_id) {
            case 0x0001: {
                // reinterpret the bytes received as struct A, copy elision
                const A* a_obj = reinterpret_cast<const A*>(buff);
                a_obj->print();
                // the above print call works correctly only if my system is big endian but not little endian
            }

            break;

            case 0x0002: {
                // reinterpret the bytes received as struct B, copy elision
                const B* b_obj = reinterpret_cast<const B*>(buff);
                b_obj->print();
                // the above print call works correctly only if my system is big endian but not little endian
            }

            break;

            case 0x0003: {
                // reinterpret the bytes received as struct C, copy elision
                const C* c_obj = reinterpret_cast<const C*>(buff);
                c_obj->print();
                // the above print call works correctly only if my system is big endian but not little endian
            }

            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}


I would probably create constructors that take the byte-buffer as argument to construct the object correctly, including conversion of data and byte-order.

Your b_obj->print(); after reinterpret_cast is Undefined Behavior, regardless of your system endianness.

@Harry look into the ntohs() and ntohl() functions. They convert 16bit and 32bit integers from network byte order into host byte order

@pptaszni is it b'coz of structure padding?

Simply because of the rules of type aliasing. You can reinterpret_cast to char* and do some operations, but not the other way around. You would need to std::memcpy your bytes to your struct first.

Related, about aliasing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983267/4165552

"without copying into a temporary variable". You can't, without violating strict aliasing rule, before C++23 introduced std::start_lifetime_as, but even with C++23 it cannot account for the difference between network byte order and host byte order.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html -- as with everything boost, it's not the most trivial thing to get into, BUT it supports all integer types and both aligned and unaligned operation.


char buff[8192];
// ...
// reinterpret the bytes received as struct A, copy elision
const A* a_obj = reinterpret_cast<const A*>(buff);
a_obj->print();


In C++, this is always undefined behavior.
It is a strict aliasing violation because buff (after array-to-pointer conversion) is a pointer to a char object, but you are accessing its print member through the type A.
That's not allowed; see [expr.ref] p9.
buff is also possibly under-aligned, and you need to use alignas(A) to ensure proper alignment for the A object potentially inside.
C++23 added a function which is perfect for this use case: std::start_lifetime_as:
alingas(A) char buff[8192];
// ...
const A* a_obj = std::start_lifetime_as<A>(buff);
a_obj->print();

For this to work, A needs to be an implicit-lifetime class type, which looks possible in your case.
Unfortunately, no compiler implements std::start_lifetime_as at the time of writing, so you'll need a workaround that's technically UB, but not obviously so:
alingas(A) char buff[8192];
// ...
const A* a_obj = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<A*>(buff));
a_obj->print();

With std::launder, you're turning a pointer to a char object into a pointer to an A object at the same address.
This is still undefined behavior if there isn't actually an A object there, but you can assume that recvfrom puts an A there.
At least, the compiler cannot prove that recvfrom has not put an A there, so it will do what you want.
Note on Endianness conversion
Keep in mind that all of these approaches assume that the given object is already in native byte order, not in network byte order.
No Endianness conversion is being performed here.
To get meaningful values for your data members, you would need to correct their byte order after reinterpretation (no matter which approach), e.g. by using std::byteswap for each member.

You can replace auto p = std::start_lifetime_as<T>(x); with char tmp[sizeof(T)]; std::memcpy(tmp, x, sizeof(T)); auto p = new (x) T; std::memcpy(x, tmp, sizeof(T));, relying on the compiler to optimize away all the useless copies.

suppose each of the structs didn't have any member functions(methods). Is performing reinterpret_cast<struct > still UB?

@PasserBy OP explicitly stated "without copying into a temporary variable". `@Harry Yes, still UB.

You can also emulate std::start_lifetime_as by doing std::memmove(buff, buff, sizeof(A)) to implicitly start the lifetime of an A object within buff but I didn't want to go too deep into these esoterics :)

@WeijunZhou I'm sure OP doesn't mean without copying in the abstract machine.

@Harry the reinterpret_cast in itself is never UB. Accessing any of the non-static members is UB (whether it's a member function or data member). The only way to make that reinterpret_cast approach valid is to never use the resulting pointer in any way, but that would be pointless. std::launder should at least trick the compiler into thinking it's okay.

I have one last doubt. In many codes I have seen people performing reinterpret_cast<sock_addr*>(&sock_addr_in) in the recvfrom socket function for the  last but one argument. is this also UB? I think inside the recvfrom function they will be accessing the member fields of the sock_addr struct.

Yes, that looks a lot like UB. People misuse reinterpret_cast a lot and I doubt it's correct in that instance.

In that case usage of C++ static_cast valid? Or it is still UB?

@Harry static_cast (between pointers) wouldn't make it any more valid than reinterpret_cast, and static_cast can only be used in specific cases (like if the source and target type are in the same inheritance hierarchy).

For char* to A*, static_cast won't compile.

if that's the case, what type of C++ style casts to use in case of recvfrom function? only usage of reinterpret_cast makes sense, rest(static_cast, dynamic_cast and const_cast) doesn't. Or I should use C style cast instead of C++ style casts? in order to have defined behavior

No cast solves this issue. You need something like std::bit_cast, std::memcpy, std::start_lifetime_as etc. to do type punning without UB. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67636231/
